# How can I pass a prop attribute in one component to other component ? (React Js)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I want the **Statistic** components to be displayed only after clicking any of the **3 buttons** that I've created. When I tried to move the **Statistic** components to **History** component(in the second return, below 'button press history: ...'), now I am facing the problem of variables not defined(good, neutral, bad, all2 are not defined). How can I use the variables that I've defined in one component so that it can be used in other component ? Here's my code,

App.js

```
import { useState } from 'react'

const History = (props) => {
  if (props.allClick.length === 0) {
    return (
      <div>
        the app is used by pressing the buttons
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div>
      button press history: {props.allClick.join(' ')}  
        
    </div>
  )
}

const Button = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={props.handleClick}> {props.text} </button>
    </div>
  )
}

const Statistic = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{props.title} {props.type} </p>
    </div>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  // save clicks of each button to its own state
  const [good, setGood] = useState(0)
  const [neutral, setNeutral] = useState(0)
  const [bad, setBad] = useState(0)
  const [allClick, setClick] = useState([])

  const inlineButton = {
    display: 'inline-flex',
    gap: '10px'
  }

  const goodClick = () => {
    setClick(allClick.concat('G'))
    setGood(good + 1)
  }

  const neutralClick = () => {
    setClick(allClick.concat('N'))
    setNeutral(neutral + 1)
  }

  const badClick = () => {
    setClick(allClick.concat('B'))
    setBad(bad + 1)
  }

  const all2 = good+neutral+bad

  return (
    <div>
      <h1> give feedback </h1>
      <div style={inlineButton}>
        <Button handleClick={goodClick} text="good"/>
        <Button handleClick={neutralClick} text="neutral"/>
        <Button handleClick={badClick} text="bad" />
      </div>

      <h1> statistics </h1>

      <History allClick={allClick} />

      <Statistic title="good" type={good}/>
      <Statistic title="neutral" type={neutral}/>
      <Statistic title="bad" type={bad}/>
      <Statistic title="all" type={all2}/>
      <Statistic title="positive" type={good/all2 * 100} />  
    
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'

import App from './App'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<App />)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do this is by passing the values down with the **props**.

App

```js
<History allClick={allClick} good={good} neutral={neutral} bad={bad} />
```

Then you can move the `Statistic` components down and pass them their props.

History

```js
const History = (props) => {
  if (props.allClick.length === 0) {
    return <div>the app is used by pressing the buttons</div>;
  }

  const all2 = props.good + props.neutral + props.bad;

  return (
    <>
      <div>button press history: {props.allClick.join(" ")}</div>
      <Statistic title="good" type={props.good} />
      <Statistic title="neutral" type={props.neutral} />
      <Statistic title="bad" type={props.bad} />
      <Statistic title="all" type={all2} />
      <Statistic title="positive" type={(props.good / all2) * 100} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for teaching me something today